# What was the first Windows NT build to support Windows Registry?

Tags: windows

The early alpha builds do not have a registry, thus I wonder what build was the first to include registry?

Comment: I did not know that early builds didn't have a registry, thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Build 196](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1_build_196) (the first release outside Microsoft, September 1991) doesn’t use the registry, although it does create a `C:\REGISTRY` directory when running.

[Build 297.1](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1_build_297.1) (the first public beta, July 1992), compared to [build 239](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1_build_239) (December 1991), drops `REG.DAT` (which is presumably a Windows 3.1-style registry) and adds the registry editor (`REGEDIT.EXE`) and a `REGISTRY.INF` which is probably registry-related. So the Windows 3.1-style registry was added somewhere between builds 196 and 239, and the NT-style registry somewhere between builds 239 and 297.1.

[Build 404.1](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1_build_404.1) (the second public beta, March 1993) adds `REGEDT32.EXE`.